# Removing whitespace from JavaScript crossfade animation - troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, css, animation, carousel, cross-fade

My JavaScript crossfade animation is simply fading out one image and fading in another image while showing whitespace (green) in-between the different images. How can I get the current image to fade out to reveal the next image in the queue using JavaScript without showing any whitespace? The crossfade should fade out the current image to reveal the next image underneath it. Is my JavaScript logic sound or do I need to rethink how it should be working? Any thoughts or troubleshooting help would be most appreciated!

```js
$(function() {
    // Default controls
    var defControls = {
        content : 'img', // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
        showControls : true, // true/false shows/hides the carousel's navigational controls
        effect : 'default', // supports default, fade, crossfade, slide, slidingFade
        duration : .25, // adjust the time of the effect measured in seconds
        prevText : '&laquo; Previous', // previous button text
        nextText : 'Next &raquo;', // next button text
        containerWidth : 600 // determines the width of the content container
    };

    // Variable declarations
    var controls = {};

    // Checks for userControls
    if (typeof userControls !== 'undefined') {
        var controls = Object.assign({}, defControls, userControls);
    } else {
        controls = defControls;
    }
    
    var contentType = $(controls.content);
    var $el = $('#showcase');
    var $leftArrow = '#left_arrow';
    var $rightArrow = '#right_arrow';
    var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
    var slideCount = $el.children().length;
    var slideNum = 1;
    
    // Preloads carousel with correct settings
    $el.css('width', controls.containerWidth);
    $load.className = 'active';

    // Checks if the content in the carousel is an img and then determines the width of the container based on the size of the content or the user defined-width
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (controls.content == 'img') {
            if (typeof userControls.containerWidth !== 'undefined') {
                $el.css('width', userControls.containerWidth);
            } else {
                controls.containerWidth = $el.children().width();
                $el.css('width', controls.containerWidth);
            }
        }
    })

    // Checks to see if the option for carousel controls are set to show on the page
    if (controls.showControls === true) {
        $('<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' + $leftArrow.replace('#', '') + '">' + controls.prevText + '</a> <a href="#" id="' + $rightArrow.replace('#', '') + '">' + controls.nextText + '</a></div>').insertAfter('#showcase');
        $('#controls').find('#left_arrow').addClass('disabled');
    }
    
    // Logic for the carousel effects
    function effects(action) {
        switch (controls.effect) {
            // Crossfade effect
            case 'crossfade':
                $('.slide').stop().animate({opacity : 0}, controls.duration*300, function() {
                    $('.active').stop().animate({opacity : 1}, controls.duration*1000);
                });
                break;
                
            // Default effect
            case 'default':
                break;
        }
    }
    
    // Checks for the first and last index in the carousel
    function checkSlide() {
        if (slideNum == 1) {
            $($leftArrow).addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $($leftArrow).removeClass('disabled');
        }
        
        if (slideNum == slideCount) {
            $($rightArrow).addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $($rightArrow).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    }

    // Navigational logic for the previous/next buttons
    $(document).on('click', $leftArrow, function(e) {
        if (slideNum > 1) {
            var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter--;
            $('.active').addClass('slide');
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            effects('prev');
            $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
            slideNum--;
            checkSlide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    
    $(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function(e) {
        if (slideNum < slideCount) {
            var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter++;
            $('.active').addClass('slide');
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            effects('next');
            $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
            slideNum++;
            checkSlide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#showcase {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: green;
}

img {
 width: 368px; /* Temporary - image width will be adjusted in the JS */
}

.disabled {
 color: red !important;
}

.slide {
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}

.active {
 display: block;
 opacity: 1;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase">
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=806" />
</div>

<script>
userControls = {
 effect : 'crossfade',
 nextText : 'Forward March!',
 prevText : 'RETREAT!',
 duration : .3
}
</script>
```

Comment: [I found this](https://jsfiddle.net/u93du28m/32/), doesn't answer your question but might give you an idea who knows.

Comment: Thanks @IslamElshobokshy, I'll take a look and comment back. :)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, unfortunately I was not able to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to set your background to white in your css file

```
#showcase {
overflow: hidden;
background: white; }
```

Comment: The problem is not the background color. I made the background green for visual purposes. No color should be showing when the image is fading out. When the image fades out the next image should immediately appear underneath.

Comment: He doesn't just want to remove the green transition effect, he wants to have the second image appear as the transition happens.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, exactly. I have updated my description. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ???

```js
$(function() {
    // Default controls
    var defControls = {
        content : 'img', // accepts any DOM element - div, img, table, etc...
        showControls : true, // true/false shows/hides the carousel's navigational controls
        effect : 'default', // supports default, fade, crossfade, slide, slidingFade
        duration : .25, // adjust the time of the effect measured in seconds
        prevText : '&laquo; Previous', // previous button text
        nextText : 'Next &raquo;', // next button text
        containerWidth : 600 // determines the width of the content container
    };

    // Variable declarations
    var controls = {};

    // Checks for userControls
    if (typeof userControls !== 'undefined') {
        var controls = Object.assign({}, defControls, userControls);
    } else {
        controls = defControls;
    }
    
    var contentType = $(controls.content);
    var $el = $('#showcase');
    var $leftArrow = '#left_arrow';
    var $rightArrow = '#right_arrow';
    var $load = $el.find(contentType)[0];
    var slideCount = $el.children().length;
    var slideNum = 1;
    
    // Preloads carousel with correct settings
    $el.css('width', controls.containerWidth);
    $load.className = 'active';

    // Checks if the content in the carousel is an img and then determines the width of the container based on the size of the content or the user defined-width
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (controls.content == 'img') {
            if (typeof userControls.containerWidth !== 'undefined') {
                $el.css('width', userControls.containerWidth);
            } else {
                controls.containerWidth = $el.children().width();
                $el.css('width', controls.containerWidth);
            }
        }
    })

    // Checks to see if the option for carousel controls are set to show on the page
    if (controls.showControls === true) {
        $('<div id="controls"><a href="#" id="' + $leftArrow.replace('#', '') + '">' + controls.prevText + '</a> <a href="#" id="' + $rightArrow.replace('#', '') + '">' + controls.nextText + '</a></div>').insertAfter('#showcase');
        $('#controls').find('#left_arrow').addClass('disabled');
    }
    
    // Logic for the carousel effects
    function effects(action) {
        switch (controls.effect) {
            // Crossfade effect
            case 'crossfade':
                $('.slide').fadeOut(400);
                $('.active').fadeIn(300);
                break;
                
            // Default effect
            case 'default':
                break;
        }
    }
    
    // Checks for the first and last index in the carousel
    function checkSlide() {
        if (slideNum == 1) {
            $($leftArrow).addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $($leftArrow).removeClass('disabled');
        }
        
        if (slideNum == slideCount) {
            $($rightArrow).addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $($rightArrow).removeClass('disabled');
        }
    }

    // Navigational logic for the previous/next buttons
    $(document).on('click', $leftArrow, function(e) {
        if (slideNum > 1) {
            var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter--;
            $('.active').addClass('slide').removeClass('active');
            
            $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
            effects(controls.effect);
            slideNum--;
            checkSlide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    
    $(document).on('click', $rightArrow, function(e) {
        if (slideNum < slideCount) {
            var counter = $('.active').index();
      counter++;
            $('.active').addClass('slide').removeClass('active');
            
            $el.find(contentType).eq(counter).addClass('active');
            effects(controls.effect);
            slideNum++;
            checkSlide();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#showcase {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 284px;
 
}

img {
 width: 368px; /* Temporary - image width will be adjusted in the JS */
}

.disabled {
 color: red !important;
}

.slide {
display:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showcase">
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=306" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=626" />
 <img class="slide" src="https://picsum.photos/458/354/?image=806" />
</div>

<script>
userControls = {
 effect : 'crossfade',
 nextText : '>>>',
 prevText : '<<<',
 duration : .2
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your solution almost works and it's something that I've tried. The problem with this implementation is that the first slide still shows green and then begins the crossfade animation. It needs to crossfade from the start.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, do you have any thoughts on this?